# HTML 5 Video with cue points

Tags: html, flash, video

Looking for a recommendation of an open-source HTML 5 video player with support for metadata (cue points).

We are using Flash video that triggers JavaScript in the host page using cue points and ExternalInterface, but the time has come for HTML 5.

I'm eager to build my own but am time constrained.  We were hoping to extend something that gets us most of the way there.  Already checked out [video.js](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/tracks.md)--  no metadata support.

We created one for Vimeo's FroogaLoop kit, but we need something not tied to a provider, nor can there be any dependency on a framework, i.e. JQuery.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Leanback Player](http://www.leanbackplayer.com/) would work well for your requirements.